# Joining two text files based on a common field (ip address)

Tags: bash, file, unix, join, awk

File1

```
abcd-efg|random1||abcd|10.10.1.1||
bcde-ab|random2||bc|10.1.2.2||
efgh-bd|ramdom3||fgh|10.2.1.1||
ijkl|random4||mno|10.3.2.3||
```

File2

```
10.10.1.1| yes
10.1.2.2| no
10.2.1.1| yes
10.3.2.3| no
```

Output should be

```
abcd-efg|random1||abcd|10.10.1.1||yes
bcde-ab|random2||bc|10.1.2.2||no
efgh-bd|ramdom3||fgh|10.2.1.1||yes
ijkl|random4||mno|10.3.2.3||no
```

I was trying to join both text files based on ip address using awk and joins but some how not able to get the right output.

Could you help me get through the right output.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0 a[$5]}' file2 file1
abcd-efg|random1||abcd|10.10.1.1|| yes
bcde-ab|random2||bc|10.1.2.2|| no
efgh-bd|ramdom3||fgh|10.2.1.1|| yes
ijkl|random4||mno|10.3.2.3|| no
```

This approach will work even if the IPs are in the files in different orders.

#### How it works

- `-F'|'`

  Set the field separator on input to `|`.
- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next}`

  When reading the first file, `file2`, save the second field as a value in associative array `a` under the key of the first field.    Skip remaining commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `print $0 a[$5]`

  If we get here, we are working on the second file, `file1`.  Print the line followed by the value of `a` for this IP.

#### BSD/OSX

On BSD (OSX) awk, try:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next;} {print $0 a[$5];}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thank you John,I ran the script but not able to get the last column(yes and no) in the output . Am i missing something?

Comment: @Babu That is curious.  I just copied-and-pasted from my answer to my terminal and it still runs fine.  Please check and see if your input files differ in any way, large or small, from the files shown in the question.

Comment: @Babu Are you, by any chance, using Sun or Solaris?

Comment: my doubt is why is it not working in mac,Is there any way I can make it work in mac too?

Comment: @Babu OSX uses BSD awk which sometimes requires minor changes in syntax.  Please see the update to the answer and let me know if that works for you.  (If it doesn't, please quote the complete error message.)

Answer (score 1):

Unix join command can be used for this

```
join -t\| -j1 5 -j2 1 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2 file1 file2
```

Explanation of options:

`-t\|`  : Field separator is '|' (escaped)

`-j1 5 -j2 1`  : Join based on 5th field of file1 and 1st field of file2

`-o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2` : Output the 6 fields from file1 and 2nd field from file2

If the input files are not sorted, they need to be sorted first, like below

```
join -t\| -j1 5 -j2 1 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2 <(sort -t'|' -k5 file1)  <(sort -t'|' -k1 file2)
```

Comment: Working fine.Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both files have IP address in same order as shown in OP's example

```
paste -d'\0' file1 <(cut -d' ' -f2 file2)
```

- `cut -d' ' -f2 file2` select second column of file2, column separation is space character specified by delimiter `-d' '`
- Using [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), output of `cut` command is passed as file input to `paste` command
- `paste` command then combines file1 and output of `cut` column wise without any character in between (reference: [paste without delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227941/paste-files-without-delimiter))